# sonarqube keeps stopping the moment it starts running

Tags: sonarqube

I'm Using Windows 10, Java 11, sonarqube-9.8.0.63668, jdk-11.0.11. I'm quite new to sonarqube, so please tell me if there is any more information that you might need.

Starting the sonarservice used to work fine. I am not sure what is wrong (I haven't changed anything in the .properties file).

I start the service by using command prompt to run the startsonar.bat file

This is what happens when I start the service in command prompt:

`C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\bin\windows-x86-64>startsonar.bat Starting SonarQube... 2023.02.19 04:48:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp 2023.02.19 04:48:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:63759] 2023.02.19 04:48:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot\bin\java -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.tmpdir=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch 2023.02.19 04:48:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running 2023.02.19 04:49:13 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up 2023.02.19 04:49:13 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[WEB_SERVER] from [C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668]: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-9.8.0.63668.jar;C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-2.1.214.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp\sq-process18020723362913653070properties WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager (file:/C:/Users/mayhe/Documents/sonarqube-9.8.0.63668/sonarqube-9.8.0.63668/lib/sonar-application-9.8.0.63668.jar) WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release 2023.02.19 04:49:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped 2023.02.19 04:49:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped 2023.02.19 04:49:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped`

ce.log:
`2023.02.04 05:11:37 WARN  ce[][c.z.h.p.HikariPool] HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=16h46m27s756ms572µs900ns).`

web.log:
`2023.02.19 03:52:43 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting Web Server 2023.02.19 03:52:45 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 9.8.0.63668 / 6498415c5112d868f6206d8bcc043a1dac92d1c4 2023.02.19 03:52:45 WARN  web[][o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd-org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to start database 2023.02.19 03:52:45 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.PlatformImpl] Web server startup failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd-org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to start database   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)  at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:187)  at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:80)   at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel1.start(PlatformLevel1.java:164)    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.start(PlatformImpl.java:196)  at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.startLevel1Container(PlatformImpl.java:162)   at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.init(PlatformImpl.java:76)    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4764)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5222)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:72)    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:55)  at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:97)    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:104) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to start database     at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabase.startServer(EmbeddedDatabase.java:88)  at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabase.start(EmbeddedDatabase.java:63)    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.start(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:49)  at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(StartableBeanPostProcessor.java:33)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)   ... 44 common frames omitted Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: Chunk 545 not found [2.1.214/9]" [50000-214]     at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:554)     at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)     at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:395)     at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:403)     at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:92)     at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:222)    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201)  at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:338)  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:122)   at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59)    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabase.createDatabase(EmbeddedDatabase.java:115)  at org.sonar.server.platform.db.EmbeddedDatabase.startServer(EmbeddedDatabase.java:79)  ... 50 common frames omitted Caused by: org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: Chunk 545 not found [2.1.214/9]    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newMVStoreException(DataUtils.java:1004)    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.getChunk(MVStore.java:1384)   at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:2566)   at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:633)    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readOrCreateRootPage(MVMap.java:658)    at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.setRootPos(MVMap.java:643)  at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.openMap(MVStore.java:702)     at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.openMap(MVStore.java:648)     at org.h2.mvstore.tx.TransactionStore.openMap(TransactionStore.java:564)    at org.h2.mvstore.db.LobStorageMap.<init>(LobStorageMap.java:136)   at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:374)     ... 60 common frames omitted    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.h2.store.LobStorageInterface.close()" because "this.lobStorage" is null      at org.h2.engine.Database.closeOpenFilesAndUnlock(Database.java:1252)       at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:399)         ... 60 common frames omitted 2023.02.19 03:52:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000 2023.02.19 03:52:46 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process`

es.log:
`2023.02.19 03:52:29 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[7.17.6], pid[11896], build[unknown/unknown/f65e9d338dc1d07b642e14a27f338990148ee5b6/2022-08-23T11:08:48.893373482Z], OS[Windows 10/10.0/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Adoptium/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/17.0.5/17.0.5+8] 2023.02.19 03:52:29 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM home [C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot] 2023.02.19 03:52:29 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp, -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djna.tmpdir=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Dcom.redhat.fips=false, -Xmx512m, -Xms512m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Delasticsearch, -Des.path.home=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=C:\Users\mayhe\Documents\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\sonarqube-9.8.0.63668\temp\conf\es] 2023.02.19 03:52:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common] 2023.02.19 03:52:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless] 2023.02.19 03:52:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join] 2023.02.19 03:52:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex] 2023.02.19 03:52:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4] 2023.02.19 03:52:30 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded 2023.02.19 03:52:30 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Windows (C:)]], net usable_space [211gb], net total_space [455.2gb], types [NTFS] 2023.02.19 03:52:30 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [512mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true] 2023.02.19 03:52:31 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [X8-rPowaSL63lggYpofZqg], cluster name [sonarqube], roles [data_frozen, master, remote_cluster_client, data, data_content, data_hot, data_warm, data_cold, ingest] 2023.02.19 03:52:36 INFO  es[][o.e.t.NettyAllocator] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, suggested_max_allocation_size=256kb, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=1mb, heap_size=512mb}] 2023.02.19 03:52:36 INFO  es[][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b] 2023.02.19 03:52:36 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings] 2023.02.19 03:52:37 INFO  es[][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually 2023.02.19 03:52:37 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized 2023.02.19 03:52:37 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ... 2023.02.19 03:52:37 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:61229}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:61229} 2023.02.19 03:52:40 INFO  es[][o.e.c.c.Coordinator] cluster UUID [IMag8vk6RwirV2vDDPYE4A] 2023.02.19 03:52:40 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.MasterService] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[{sonarqube}{X8-rPowaSL63lggYpofZqg}{9YWVEDtPSsy0Vr28ywzEow}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:61229}{cdfhimrsw} elect leader, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 113, version: 2234, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{sonarqube}{X8-rPowaSL63lggYpofZqg}{9YWVEDtPSsy0Vr28ywzEow}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:61229}{cdfhimrsw}]} 2023.02.19 03:52:40 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] master node changed {previous [], current [{sonarqube}{X8-rPowaSL63lggYpofZqg}{9YWVEDtPSsy0Vr28ywzEow}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:61229}{cdfhimrsw}]}, term: 113, version: 2234, reason: Publication{term=113, version=2234} 2023.02.19 03:52:40 INFO  es[][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001} 2023.02.19 03:52:40 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] started 2023.02.19 03:52:40 INFO  es[][o.e.g.GatewayService] recovered [7] indices into cluster_state 2023.02.19 03:52:43 INFO  es[][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[components][2], [components][0], [metadatas][0]]]).`

When I open up the localhost I get a "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect" error.

I have tried deleting some of the projects that I've already tried analyzing and played around a bit with the .properties file in the conf folder, but couldn't get anywhere. I have tried asking on the sonar community forum, I didn't receive any answer.

I have also tried re-extracting the files from the original zip that I downloaded and tried running the service using the "other" startsonar.bat file.

I was expecting the service to run as usual. I have no idea why, only since a few weeks ago, it started stopping itself immediately after starting